# Is edge.js available to c# dll file (compiling at window) runs with nodejs at linux(centos)?

Tags: c#, node.js, dll, edge.js

Is edge.js available to c# dll file (compiling at window) runs with nodejs at linux(centos)?

A developer in my team programming c# in Windows.

I want to reuse her code without re-coding in Linux.

I am using node.js.

We found out edge modules makes c# dll script from node.js in Windows.

But we are not sure if it works in other OS or not.

c# DLL - compiled in windows,

node.js - Linux (centos)

Comment: You are a node.js developer on linux, and you want to use a code from windows C# developer? And you want to write C# code inside your JS code on Linux, that will load a C# assembly, compiled on windows, and then will do some work?

Comment: @vasily.sib I mean I want to use dll file. because edge.js can work with dll.

Comment: The easiest way to know it is to try it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its a normal use case.

```
edge.func(`
  #r "Library.dll"
  // Other C# code using that library from Node
```